# I would like to add country of origin to products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi I would like to add country of origin while adding products and then sort products based on country of origin
Can I achieve this?

Comment: the answer is yes ;-)

Comment: The code below works perfectly but I want to display it front end in Dokan

Comment: The code below works perfectly but I want to display it front end in dokan store for vendors

Answer (score 1):

Add these functions to your theme's 'functions.php'.

> Display & Save the Custom Field in Admin

```
// display field in admin
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_country_field');
function woocommerce_product_country_field()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    $countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
    $options   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');

    echo '<div class="product_country_field">';
    woocommerce_wp_select(
        array(
            'id' => '_country_origin',
            'label' => __('Country of origin', 'woocommerce'),
            'options' => $options,
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}

// save fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_country_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_country_fields_save($post_id)
{  
    $woocommerce_country_origin = $_POST['_country_origin'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_country_origin))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_country_origin', esc_attr($woocommerce_country_origin));

}
```

> Sort by Custom Field in Front-End

```
// sort field
function custom_add_country_ordering_args( $sort_args ) {       
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    switch( $orderby_value ) {

        case '_country_origin':
            $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value';
            $sort_args['order']    = 'asc';
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = '_country_origin';
            break;      
        case '_country_origin-desc':
            $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value';
            $sort_args['order']    = 'desc';
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = '_country_origin';
            break;  
    }

    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_add_country_ordering_args' );

//change sort dropdown
function custom_add_country_orderby( $sortby ) {
    //remove default sorting
    unset($sortby["popularity"]);
    unset($sortby["rating"]);
    unset($sortby["date"]);
    unset($sortby["price"]);
    unset($sortby["price-desc"]); 

    $sortby['_country_origin'] = __( 'Sort by Country of origin', 'woocommerce' );  
    $sortby['_country_origin-desc'] = __( 'Sort by Country of origin descending', 'woocommerce' ); 

    return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_add_country_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_add_country_orderby' );
```

Please note that the products which has 'Country of origin' will only be displayed while sorting.

> Filter by Custom Field in Front-End

Add this if you want filter rather than sort.

```
//add custom filter
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'filter_loop_start' );
function filter_loop_start( $query ){
    $countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
    $options   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');
    ?>
    <form name="product_filter_form" class="woocommerce-filtering" method="get">
        <select name="country_origin" class="filterby" onChange="document.product_filter_form.submit();">
        <option value="">Filter by Country of origin</option>
        <?php foreach ($options as $key => $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"<?php if($_GET['country_origin']==$key) echo ' selected'; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input name="paged" value="1" type="hidden">
    </form>
<?php
}

//modify query for filter
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_modify_main_query' );
function my_modify_main_query( $query ) {
    if( ! isset( $_GET['country_origin'] ) ) return $query;

    $meta_query_args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_country_origin',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['country_origin'] ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
    );
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_args);

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ok it is working perfectly when logged in to wordpress as admin. I am using Dokan and this code is not displaying country of origin front end when a vendor adds a product is there a way to display it front end ?

Comment: The above code will show the sorting in front-end WooCommerce shop page and you need to update country for each product via admin panel. What you want to show in front-end?

Comment: I want to show country of origin when vendors are adding products through their store front end because dokan doesn't allow them to go inside wordpress admin panel when logged in

Comment: I am using wc front end dashboard

Comment: This post might help you - https://wedevs.com/support/topic/adding-metadata-to-product-form/.

Comment: Let me know whether you can manage using above post or need further assistance.

Comment: Hi I would like to add a separate select box with all the countries in product page independent from woocommerce sorting options how can I do this?

Comment: Instead of `$options   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');` in `woocommerce_product_country_field()` function, use your own array of countries list.

Comment: I think you understood me wrong in the shop page you have all the sorting options like default sorting and sort by price etc .. I want another select box on the left with all countries to select from

Comment: It may be complicated since there will be more than one 'order by query'.

Comment: I ll hide the other sorting options

Comment: So, there will be only one sorting option - country right?

Comment: I will update once I got PC access, in the mean time you can try this - https://www.templatemonster.com/help/woocommerce-how-to-remove-some-options-from-the-sort-by-list.html.

Comment: hi thanks but it is still not opening a list of countries for the user to choose from

Comment: Oh you need country filtering right, not the sort? :)

Comment: yeahh just to open a list of countries and filter according to country of origin similar to those in the admin

Comment: Check my updated answer, replace the sort part with filter.

Comment: You have been a great help thank you alot .. Please let me know if you need help with anything so I can return the favor. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help you, thanks :) Accept my answer if helpful.